# Find the prime $ P $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Find the prime $ P $ whose sum $ S $ of all primes less than or equal to $ P $ is also a prime, and can be found by the expression:

$$ S = P ^ 2-88P +  1976$$

$$ S < 1000 $$

I tried $ S = (E-44) ^ 2 + 50 $, I put $ A = 59 $, I think I limited the sum between $ 50 $ and $ 100 $, but I wanted a method without testing and thinking about values as much as possible, only with variables

Comment: If $1$ is prime, then $P=67$ and $S=569$. None other $P$.

Answer (score 1):

This questions doesn't make sense to me. If you claim that the sum $S$ of all primes less than or equal to $P$-prime is also a prime, can be found by $S = P^2-88P+1976$,this should hold for $P=7$; as the sum of all the primes up to 7 is 2+3+5+7=17, which is prime. But, your formula gives, $S = 7^2 - 88*7+1976 = 1409$, which clearly is wrong.